# Write to Python file without losing current content (inserting)

Tags: python, file-io

My code:

```
import os
file_handle = open("/home/naseer/Python/newfile","r+")
file_handle.seek(6)
file_handle.write("hai\n")
```

My *newfile* content:

```
opera\n
mount\n
singapore
```

In my code, I'm seeking the end of `opera` (first line) of my *newfile* and I want to write `hai\n` there, i.e. I want to make my *newfile* like below:

```
opera\n
hai\n
mount\n
singapore
```

But my code overwrites the current content of my file, which is not what I want:

```
opera\n
hai\n
t\n
singapore
```

This is not appending and as per my knowledge, there is a specific mode of opening the file to achieve this. I don't know if this kind of requirement is illegal.

If this is illegal, why?

Comment: It's for sure illegal, you might want to take this question down before the police show up

Comment: No Not append `a`. why I cant I do this please explain

Comment: So you want to insert `hai\\n` into the file at some point?

Comment: Not `hai\\n` but `hai\n`

Comment: Why should I loose my content. Please explain . I want  something to be added in between to my file , just assume.

Comment: text files and read/write mode don't mix well. You have to read the file, insert a line and write it back

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to *insert* a new line into the file, but `.write()` doesn't work like that; it *overwrites* the existing file contents.

Instead, you should create a new file with the desired content, delete the old file, and rename the new file to the old filename.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But my question is If seek method is facilitated it would help in reading certain things from a file, why cant the same seek method help in writing something to file with out deleting its previous content?

Comment: Because that's just not how it works.  Imagine the file is a piece of paper, and you're writing on it with a pencil.  Seeking lets you put the pencil anywhere on the paper, but writing just scribbles over the existing letters.  If you want to _insert_ letters, you have to erase the rest of the paper, write the new letters, then rewrite the old letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = '/home/naseer/Python/newfile'

data = None

with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('opera\\n', 'opera\\n hai\\n')

with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(data)
```

What about this?

The input file looks like this:

```
opera\n mount\n singapore
```

While after running this script:

```
opera\n hai\n mount\n singapore
```

Comment: Yes It works. But `replace('opera\n', 'opera\nhai\n')` has to be edited. But with help of seek is what I wanted. Thanks It helped

Comment: `'r+'` isn't necessary here. r is enough

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
file_handle=open("/home/naseer/Python/newfile","r+")
```

To :

```
file_handle=open("/home/naseer/Python/newfile","a") 
file_handle.write("hai\n")
```

"r" stands for writing erassng the previous data and "a" for append.
As you want to add a new line append should work for you.

Comment: Her wants to add a new line in the middle of the file.  `"a"` will not work for this case.